Code to build the monoclinic crystal lattice
Benzoic acid exists as a solid at room temperature. So, I want to build a monoclinic crystal structure of this molecule. Is there any code available to do that? Thanks.
Edit: Is there any way to build a crystal lattice from the information of the unit cell?

Try VESTA, check fractional coordinate from literature https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/1996/ft/ft9969205051

Thanks Pranav. Can I just use the coordinates, like that from a pdb file? I have never used VESTA though.

Here you have a crystal structure: http://doi.org/10.5517/ccvfcxj (CCDC)

Thanks a lot @marcin. So, can I use this unit cell information, and duplicate it in all directions to form a crystal?

That information is already a complete description of crystal structure. It's unclear what you want to achieve. Multiplicating the unit cell creates so-called supercell, which is useful in some simulations. Similarly, you could repeat the unit cell to build a model of a nano-sized crystalline grain. But if you just want a crystal structure, it's defined by the content of the unit cell, you don't need to change anything.

Thanks @marcin Sorry, I may not have elaborated my question further. So, I was trying to build a crystal lattice of this molecule for running molecular dynamics simulation. For this, I just duplicated the unit cell, which for this system encloses four molecules along x, y and z axes. I hope that’s the correct way to build the lattice for this system.
